# How to refer to a file in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using retrofit to connect my app to the server, and for that I need to refer the link of the server. However, I don't want to put said link hardcoded, I would be better if it referred to a file. How should I do this?

Here is the where I want to replace the string with the file:

```
object RetrofitClient {
private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("SERVER_LINK__Replace with file")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()

fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
    return retrofit.create(service)
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a string resource in Android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource though there won't be much of a benefit, really, This is constant anyway, there's little reason not to code it as such.

Comment: So if you don't write it there, you are gonna write it in another file? So it is not gonna be hardcoded there but in a file?